# Answering Amen After One Has Finished Sim Shalom/Shalom Rav

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, amen

If one has finished Sim Shalom/Shalom Rav AND has said Yehiyiu L'Ratzon he may answer to kaddish and Yehei Shmei Rabbah. However, should he/may he answer Amen to the other blessings in Chazarat HaShatz? i.e, ata chonen, goel ysiroel, etc.

What if he has already said the SECOND Yehiyiu L'Ratzon after Elokei Nitzor - would it change?

Comment: Hi Dov, are you suggesting there is some sort of "hefsek" between "Yehihiu" and "Elokei Nitzor", by answering simple amens to to the Shatz, while Kaddish is too important to worry about such a "hefsek"? Further, are you suggesting there is a possible similar "hefsek" issue between the second "Yehiyiu" and backing up with "Oseh Shalom" etc.?

Comment: See *Shulchan 'Aruch* ([OC 122:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%91)) and the *Mishna B'rura* [there](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%91).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rav Eliezer Melamed in his comprehensive and well-organized Peninei Halakha (17:12) [explains](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-17-12/)

> From the beginning of Elokai netzor until the second time
> Yih’yu l’ratzon is recited, one is permitted to respond to Kaddish,
> Kedushah, Barchu, and Modim – like the law regarding one who is in the
> middle of Birkot Keriat Shema – because the person praying has already
> concluded the main part of the Amidah. Nevertheless, since he did not
> entirely finish the prayer, he is prohibited from answering Amen after
> berachot or anything similar.

For the second question:

> Upon the conclusion of the prayers of supplication, the person praying
> recites Yih’yu l’ratzon again and takes three steps backwards. If he
> cannot step backwards because the person behind him is still praying,
> even though he has not yet departed from the Amidah, he may respond
> aloud to any matter of sanctity, even “Baruch Hu u’varuch Shemo,”
> since he already finished the supplications after the Amidah.
> Similarly, he is permitted to continue praying, reciting Ashrei and
> Aleinu L’Shabe’ach, or he may recite Psalms or learn Torah (see
> further in this chapter, halachah 20).